# Нужна js функция для валидации пароля

Tags: javascript, валидация, пароль, password

у меня input для пароля и нужна js функция, которая будет валидировать мой пароль, и вернуть мне true или false.  Ни как не могу понять откуда можно начинать.
Пароль должен содержать буквы, не должен начинаться с цифры, не должен содержать пробел и эти символы "-","(",")","/".
Нужно написать на обычном JavaScript.

Comment: В чем собственно проблема?

Comment: Сама функция-проблема

Comment: Не забудьте на сервере сделать тоже самое.

Comment: Я не совсем по теме, но как достают сайты, которые заставляют меня хитровыкручивать свой пароль, чтоб он подошёл под их дикие шаблоны. Вы что, в mainframe этот пароль хранить будете? Откуда все эти ограничения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте несколько регулярных выражений:

```
const beginWithoutDigit = /^\D.*$/
const withoutSpecialChars = /^[^-() /]*$/
const containsLetters = /^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*$/

let password = "12345abcde"

if( beginWithoutDigit.test(password) &&
    withoutSpecialChars.test(password) &&
    containsLetters.test(password) ){
    console.log('ok');
} else {
    console.log('wrong');
}
```

при таком подходе легко добавлять другие условия.
Например:

```
const minimum8Chars = /^.{8,}$/
const withoutSpaces = /^[\S]$/
...
```

```js
const password_field = document.getElementById("password_field")
const message = document.getElementById("message")
let password

const beginNotDigit = /^\D.*$/
const withoutSpecialChars = /^[^-() ]*$/
const containсLetters = /^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*$/

function check(){
 password = password_field.value
 message.innerHTML = "password \""+password+"\""
  if( beginNotDigit.test(password) &&
      withoutSpecialChars.test(password) &&
      containсLetters.test(password) ){
   message.innerHTML += " is allowed!"
  } else {
   message.innerHTML += " is not allowed!"
  }
}
```

```html
Password:<br>
<input id="password_field" type="password"/><br>
<button onclick="check()"> Click Me for Password</button><br>
<div id="message"></div>
```